# What is the difference between redux tool kit query and create asynx thunk?

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

I understand the how to use create async thunk and redux tool it query, if redux tool kit query solves pending, fulfilled, rejected and also catches the data then whats the use of create async thunk which main purpose is that and stores data in store.

Answer (score 4):

`cAT` is a generalized building block, RTK Query is a specialized single purpose tool. RTK Query uses `cAT` internally, essentially as if you were doing that by hand - but with very few code.

It saves you dozens of lines of code per endpoint, provided caching api data is exactly what you want to do.

That said, I'm not 100% you really grasp both those tools and what they do for you. I'd recommend you go through chapters 5-8 of [the official Redux tutorial](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts) as those will show you both those tools in-depth.

Comment: u should study about react-query , how it manages the loading state, error, data after making a http call without mantaining a seperate state by ourself .

Comment: You realize that I'm the author of RTK Query and React Query lists us as an alternative client with a very similar featureset on their webpage? With RTK Query you do not need to manage a separate state by yourself, it is taken care of for you, just like it is with React Query. We are on very friendly terms with the authors of React Query and know the featureset of the "competing tools" quite well.

Comment: sorry for the above comment sir. i dint  know that your the Author of that module And Nyc talking to u .

Comment: thanks @phry, this was a helpful explanation

Answer (score 0):

The most common use case for side effects in Redux apps is fetching data. Redux apps typically use a tool like thunks, sagas, or observables to make an AJAX request, and dispatch actions based on the results of the request. Reducers then listen for those actions to manage loading state and cache the fetched data.

RTK Query is purpose-built to solve the use case of data fetching. While it can't replace all of the situations where you'd use thunks or other side effects approaches, using RTK Query should eliminate the need for most of that hand-written side effects logic.

RTK Query is expected to cover a lot of overlapping behaviour that users may have previously used createAsyncThunk for, including caching purposes, and request lifecycle management (e.g. isUninitialized, isLoading, isError states).

In order to migrate data-fetching features from existing Redux tools to RTK Query, the appropriate endpoints should be added to an RTK Query API slice, and the previous feature code deleted. This generally will not include much common code kept between the two, as the tools work differently and one will replace the other.
Read: [Learn More] [1] https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/migrating-to-rtk-query

Answer (score -1):

I also suggest you read through the official document https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts and https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/migrating-to-rtk-query
after that, you will know everything(why and what's the best practice of RTK)

what I learnt:

- RTK cAT(create asynx thunk) can not only handle the requests but also other async, such as `setTimeout`
- once you are using cAT to handle requests, you can use RTK query to do the same thing. besides, there are a lot of benefits to using RTK query.

  - RTK query can cache data, and retry request
  - using RTK query, you don't have to write too many boilerplate codes
  - RTK query can be use in many components

**In a word, if you are handle requests, please use RTK query.**